# Given $q(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+ ... + a_n x^n$, prove $B$ and $B'$ are bases of $V$ and obtain coordinates of $q(x)$ with respect to each of them

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, change-of-basis

Given $V=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]:grad(p(x))\leq n \}$ and the polynomial $q(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+ ... + a_n x^n$ in V.

a) If $c\in \mathbb{R}$, prove $B = \{1,x-c,(x-c)^2,...,(x-c)^n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and find the coordinates of $q(x)$ relative to $B$.

b) Prove $B' = \{1,x,x (x-1),x (x-1) (x-2),...,x (x-1) (x-2) ... (x-n+1)\}$ is a basis of $V$ and find the coordinates of $q(x)$ relative to $B$.

---

My attempt at a solution:

a) Given that every element of $B$ is in $V$, $B$ is a basis of $V$ iff the elements in $B$ are linearly independent and they are in the same number as the dimension of $V$.

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &...  &0 \\ 
-c &1  &0  &...  &0 \\ 
c^2 &  &...  &  &0 \\ 
 &  &...  &  & \\ 
 (-c)^n&  &...  &  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

We can *guess* (I don't really know how to *prove* this, nor do I think is necessary) that this is a triangular matrix, so the condition given in the previous statement holds, thus $B$ is a basis of $V$.
The smartest way I can give the coordinates of $q(x)$ in this basis is
$$q_B =P \begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\ 
a_1 \\ 
... \\ 
a_n \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$
I don't know how to give a more elaborate and forthright formula for each coordinate or if there's an easy way to get it.

b) In the same fashion, I can calculate some coordinates of the polynomials in $B'$,
$$P'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... &0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... &0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 1 &0  & 0 & ... &0 \\ 
0 &2  &-3 & 1 & 0 & ... &0 \\ 
0 &-6  &11  & -6 & 1 & ... &0 \\ 
 &  &  & ... &  &  & \\ 
0 &  &  & ... &  &  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
and guessing it is a triangular matrix, if we follow the same reasoning as above we get to a similar conclusion.

I didn't know how to get a formula for $P$ and I'm even more perplexed with $P'$. So the only correct way I can find to give the coordinates is as timid as before
$$q_{B'} =P' \begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\ 
a_1 \\ 
... \\ 
a_n \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

Any help and advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: $$q=Mp\iff p=M^{-1}q$$ Both matrices are indeed triangular because the degrees of the polynoimials go increasing and the leading coefficient is 11. Hence these matrices are invertible and inversion is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) The coordinates of $q(x)$ in the canonical basis are $(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)$.
Now, with respect to B, we got to solve
$$q(x)=b_0+b_1(x-c)+b_2(x-c)^2+...+b_n(x-c)^n$$
Now, $q(c)=b_0$

If we differentiate, $$q'(x)=b_1+2b_2(x-c)+...+nb_n(x-c)^{n-1}$$
And so, $q'(c)=b_1$

If we keep going, $$q''(c)=2b_2$$
$$q'''(c)=3\ 2b_3$$
$$...$$

And we can guess that

$$q_{B}=(q(c),q'(c),\frac{q''(c)}{2},...,\frac{q^{(n)}(c)}{n!})$$

---

b) In a similar fashion,
$$q(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x(x-1)+...+b_nx(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$$
$$q(0)=b_0$$
$$q(1)=b_1$$
$$...$$
$$q(n)=n!b_n$$
And we can guess:
$$q_{B'}=(q(0),q(1),\frac{q(2)}{2},...,\frac{q(n)}{n!})$$

Comment: @Naive I think I got it. But I'm still confused about the other answers though.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients of the direct matrices are given by the Binomial numbers (Pascal's triangle) times the powers of $-c$, and the Stirling numbers respectively.

The matrices are readily inverted by the resolution of the linear system which is in echelon form:

$$\begin{align}&ax&=A\\&bx+cy&=B\\&dx+ey+fz&=C\\&gx+hy+iz+jt&=D,\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}ax&=A\\cy&=B-bx\\fz&=C-dx-ey\\jt&=D-gx-hy-iz.\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _The matrices are readily inverted_. Why would I invert them? Which is the change-of-basis matrix from canonical to $B$, $P$ or $P^T$? It's $P$, isn't it?

Comment: @Alberto: did you miss my comment ?

Comment: No, and I already knew they are invertible. I mean that I don't need to invert them to do anything, do I? Unless the change-of-basis matrices from canonical to $B$ and $B'$ are not  $P$ and $P'$, respectively.

Comment: @Alberto: you need canonical to $B$, not the converse.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, $dim(V)=n+1$ and $|B|=n+1$.

So to show that $B$ is a basis for $V$, it is enought to show that $B$ is linearly independent, because any set of $n+1$ linearly independent vectors must be a basis for $V$.

Consider,
$a_0+a_1(x-c)+a_2(x-c)^2...+a_n(x-c)^n=0$.

On using binomial expansion and clubbing the terms according to the powers of $x$ we get,

$a_nx^n+(a_{n-1}-na_n)x^{n-1}+...+(\text{some combination of} \;a_i's)x+(\text{some combination of} \;a_i's).1=0$

Since $\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$ is a basis for $V$ $\implies$ All coefficients in the above expression must be $0$

Thus, $a_n=0$, $a_{n-1}-na_n=0$,...

$\implies a_i=0 \;\; \forall i=0,1,...,n$

So $B$ is Linearly Independent and hence it forms a Basis for $V$

Now to find the coordinates of $q(x)$ relative to $B$, first you must find the Change of Basis matrix from $B'$ to $B$, here $B'$ dentes the standard basis for $V$

If $Q$ is a change of basis matrix then, $[q(x)]_{\displaystyle B}=Q[q(x)]_{\displaystyle B'}$

Comment: I did noticed that, if you read more carefully. And everything else, it's another way to do it, but my answer is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @Alberto Your idea to find the coordinates of $q(x)$ relative to $B$ is absolutely correct. But I guess the change of coordinate matrix $P$ is incorrect. I suggest you to revise the computational procedure to find change of basis matrix.

Comment: I need to solve $$a_0+a_1 x+...+a_n x^n = \lambda_0 1+\lambda_1 (x-c)+...+\lambda (x-c)^n$$  $$\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\ 
a_1 \\ 
... \\ 
a_n \\  
\end{pmatrix} =P^T \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_0 \\ 
\lambda_1 \\ 
... \\ 
\lambda_n \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$? (Here I'm talking about the $P$ in my answer)

Comment: @Alberto Are you trying to compute change of basis matrix? or something else?

Comment: well, I'm very confused. The problem asks for the coordinates in $B$, and I suppose I have to compute first the inverse of $P^{T}$, which would be the change-of-basis matrix from the canonical to $B$? But I'm having trouble finding the inverse of both matrices in the two parts of the problem

Comment: @Alberto Don't complicate things so much. There is an easier way of finding the change of basis matrix which avoids things like finding inverses.

Comment: I got confused. The change-of-basis matrix is $P$. The formula in the comments above is wrong and the expressions in the questions are right.